# How to stop WPF TopMost flag on parent window from being inherited by the child

Tags: wpf, window, topmost

I have a WPF window that has TopMost=true . When I call another Window from this window and specify the topmost window as the parent the owned window also displays as TopMost.

I would like to find a way to stop that from happening so that my parent can still own the child yet the child does not have TopMost=True.

I know I can just not bother to set the owner on the child then I won't get the TopMost flag, but I need all my windows to close with the parent window and writing the logic to handle that seems like a waste when it is included.

I've tried to explicitly set the TopMost=False after the child was loaded but no luck, it doesn't seem to matter if the owner window is TopMost then the child will be no matter what I do to it's TopMost property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set The TopMost of the (parent) window, at runtime. (and not by default)